# One Plus devices biometric prompt is dismissed after first failed

Tags: biometrics, android-fingerprint-api, android-biometric-prompt, oneplus6t, oneplus7

I am using [BiometricPrompt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt) on my app. When I am trying to use on OnePlus devices and validate the fingerprint with another finger that is not enrolled on the OS, it will trigger the `onAuthenticationFailed()` callback and the biometricPrompt will be dismissed. This happen at first try. Is it possible to let the user to failed multiple times (on documentation we have 5 times in 30 secs and after the 5'th attempt should trigger `onAuthenticationError(int errorCode,                                @NonNull CharSequence errString)` with 7 as error code) without dismissing the dialog?